# Import UTF-8 characters from database to R Studio

Tags: r, sql-server, utf-8, character-encoding

I am querying data from a SQL Server database to R Studio. Some columns contain cyrillic letters that should be used in further analysis. However they are encoded in wrong way, so I can not use them. Due to work privacy I am gonna create reproducible example that shows the problem.

```
library(odbc)
library(pool)
library(DBI)
poolX <- dbPool(drv = odbc::odbc(),
               Driver = "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
               Database = "database",
               Server = "server",
               UID = "user",
               PWD = "123456")
```

Connection works well and let R Studio query data from needed database. Database contains table with characters.

Column City contains city names written on Russian.

It's shown in SQL Server as:

```
City = Алматы, Астана
```

However when I query this column to RStudio cell it's written in this form:

```
City = <c0><eb><ec><e0><f2><fb>,<c0><f1><f2><e0><ed><e0>
```

Also R shows it in different form
    unique(City)
    #[1] "\xc0\xeb\xec\xe0\xf2\xfb"
    #[2]    "\xc0\xf1\xf2\xe0\xed\xe0"

Interesting point is, if I import data from the SQL Server database to Excel and upload to R Studio, it works well

I need direct connection from database to RStudio, so I have to fix this issue.
Any help is welcome. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your locale to Russian before you import from MSSQL with

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "Russian")
```

If you do not want set everything to Russian, you can just set the language with

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "Russian")
```

Example:

```
> City = "Алматы, Астана"
> data.frame(City)
                                                                                                City
1 <U+0410><U+043B><U+043C><U+0430><U+0442><U+044B>, <U+0410><U+0441><U+0442><U+0430><U+043D><U+0430>
> Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "Russian")
[1] "Russian_Russia.1251"
> 
> data.frame(City)
            City
1 Алматы, Астана
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately it does not work. Important think is cyrillic ("russian") letters are shown in some different way. Letters look like this: 
      <d7><e5><f0><ed><ee><e2><e0><ff> while numbers and words written on latin works well